# "Вовсю" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Как пишется "во()всю": слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наречие "вовсю" пишется одним словом.

Answer (score 2):

Наречие пишется раздельно, если местоимение, входящее в его состав, имеет ведущее слово. Например: во всю ширь. Здесь ширь - ведущее слово. Слитно пишутся наречия, образованные из предлога и местоимения, не имеющие ведущего слова. В этом случае вовсю пишется уже слитно.

Answer (score 0):

Во всю прыть, но улыбался вовсю. Наречие